# How should I partition My Disk

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I'm installing Ubuntu 20.04.3 LST on my PC and I'm doing a complete install uninstalling windows 10.
My Ram - 4GB , SDD - 480GB , HDD - 500GB. I'm a little confused about where to give appropriate space. please help me out. [Is doing this is ok ? the upper 4 partitions are from sdd - 480GB and the lower one is hdd - 500GB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzOTO.png)

Comment: We all have different needs, so the best partitioning layout is best decided for your end end-use case of your system. You haven't provided any OS & release details, nor how you'll use the system (and this site doesn't like *opinion* geared questions as I see your question; Forums are better for that), but I believe simple is best. I'd not have use a /boot partition (let it use your / partition; it's one less thing to watch space wise) & not use /usr/local/ for your sdb1; but I'd likely use /data or something unique you like (purely subjective what's best here!) otherwise it's okay by me

Comment: @guiverc System prompts to have a /boot partition

Comment: A prompt for `/boot/efi` I'd expect for an uEFI/secure-uEFI system, but not a /boot; but you've not said if you're talking about Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop, or Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server

Comment: @guiverc yaa yaa that one I'm completely new to linux.... I used Kali when I was new then I understood why people say don't use kali so now I'm trying Ubuntu btw I'm talking about Ubuntu 20.04.0 LTS Desktop

Comment: Personally I'd forget about sdb/sdb1 with your install; add that adding that later to your system (ie. not during the install process).   I'd recommend keeping it simple (ie. KISS) You don't need much space in /boot/efi (300MB-512MB is plenty; it also must be fat32   (I'd add your sdb1 manually to your *file-system table* (ie. `/etc/fstab`) yourself, wherever you want.. eg. i used /data in prior comment; but it can be anything that makes sense to you; I have /external on one box for it's external USB drive as that made sense to me; my storage on this box is /de2900; name of server it's on)

Comment: Ok, Thank You So Much

Comment: I personally think you have overpartitioned. Unless you have a very clear and purposeful reason for having all of these different partitions, you should install Ubuntu on the fewest partitions possible. IMO, organization is a poor reason to partition since folders and mount points do the exact same thing and don't create rigid, inflexible restrictions on how the space is used. Also a swap partition is no longer necessary as a swap file will be created instead.

Answer (score 0):

Normaly you have to add a efi-partition on your SSD, 100MByte would be okay.
I use Linux for more than 12 years now and separate /boot and /home was not useful.
You should add on your SSD:

- efi-partition (100MByte as fat32 - Mounted as /boot/efi)
- / Partition ~480GByte (with home and boot)

On your HDD you can put all your personal stuff.

- I have created a folder with the name "Data" in my home directory and there I have mounted (with help of /etc/fstab) the Data-Partition.
  Then you have to change the owner-settings of this folder, so that you can put your data in this folder.

In the Data-folder (HDD) I have everythng I need (pictures, music, video, documents, other programs like several versions of eclipse)

In /home/user I have nearly nothing, only something what is system related.
The desktop (/home/user/desktop) and all the folders (pictures, videos, documents) can be changed from the user-folder to /home/user/Data/desktop , /home/user/Data/pictures, /home/user/Data/documents and so on, if you want.

You can do this if you change the path in the file "/home/user/.config/user-dirs.dirs".